# Tools for performing HTTP FLOOD attack?

Tags: tools, denial-of-service, flooding

I'm looking for tools which can perform **HTTP FLOOD ATTACK** .

I seached a lot and this is the only tool I've found [DoSHTTP](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/doshttp.htm).

Does anyone know another tool?

I want to test them on my *localhost* to find which one is the best.

Comment: A further elaboration of your testing scenario might a help for more detailed answer. i.e How you intent to perform HTTP flooding

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A "flood attack" is when you drown a target server under a lot of request. Each request entails some effort from the client, and some effort from the server; the DoS is effective when the server gives up before the client. This means that either the per-request effort from the client was less than the per-request effort from the server, or, more often, that the client mustered more CPU and network bandwidth (that's the idea behind a [Distributed Denial of Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Distributed_attack)).

If you attack "localhost", then you run both the server and the client on the same machine, which means that:

- The client and server work share the CPU resources, and will drown simultaneously.
- The network bandwidth between client and server will be extremely fast.

Both conditions mean that whatever you measure in such a situation will not be representative of what a flood attack is, how long your server would resist such a flood, and how efficient a given tool is.

Also, making a lot of HTTP requests is a rather simple programming exercise, a matter of 50 lines of code with any decent programming framework. One could argue that if you cannot do that, then you do not know enough to meaningfully interpret the results of any simulation of HTTP flooding that you may run on any set of machines.

Answer (score 3):

There are different tools available for performing web application stress testing. You can use these stress testing tools to benchmark performance against DoS attacks. Following are some tools

1. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
2. [OpenSTA](http://www.opensta.org/)
3. [Web Capacity Analysis Tool (WCAT)](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-%28x86%29)
4. [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
5. [Web Application Stress Tools](http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/servers/web_application_stress_tools.htm)

I further recommend reading about various performance optimization techniques used to offload some load from the servers

1. Load Balancing: A server or a device that balances inbound requests
   across two or  more  web servers to spread the load.
2. Caching: Cache static content from the web servers behind it and
       thereby reduce the load on the web servers

Answer (score 2):

Apache Benchmark, a tool to benchmark webservers, is not a DoS tool, but it can be used for it.

Comment: AB will only accept requests for the same Apache server where it is run at. This makes it of rather limited use even for stress-testing, let alone HTTP FLOOD-ing as Tom has already explained why. It is a performance analysis tool, end even then results should only be compared to runs on the same server. It tells almost nothing on how the server would perform, if these were external requests. As a developer, I use it to fast test (not in any way to be considered _verbose_ testing) how certain changes in my code _'might'_ impact overall server load and response times.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following tools :

1. Slowhttpattack/ Slowris
2. HOIC Flooder
3. Httpflooder
4. LOIC

etc